# How to force a hover state with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Please, considere this CSS code:

```
a { color: #ffcc00; }
a:hover { color: #ccff00; }
```

This HTML code:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>
<button id="btn">Click here</button>
```

And, finally, this JS code:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $("#link").trigger("hover");
});
```

I would like to make my link uses its pseudo-class :hover when the button is clicked.
I tried to trigger events like mousemove, mouseenter, hover etc, but anyone works.
Notice that I want to force the use of the my CSS pseudo-class :hover specification and not use something like:

```
$("#link").css("color", "ccff00");
```

Some one know how do I do this? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You will have to use a class, but don't worry, it's pretty simple. First we'll assign your `:hover` rules to not only apply to physically-hovered links, but also to links that have the classname `hovered`.

```
a:hover, a.hovered { color: #ccff00; }
```

Next, when you click `#btn`, we'll toggle the `.hovered` class on the `#link`.

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $("#link").toggleClass("hovered");
});
```

If the link has the class already, it will be removed. If it doesn't have the class, it will be added.

Comment: #jonathan its working fine. is there any other way to implement the same without adding a.hovered.

Comment: @ArulSidthan checkout the answer from Mike. Triggering 'mouseover' instead of 'hover' does what you are looking for.

Comment: Was afraid of duplicate and didn't think about this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Note: For me, this solution only worked when I duplicated the CSS definition without `a:focus` in it.

Answer (score 36):

Also, you could try triggering a mouseover.

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $("#link").trigger("mouseover");
});
```

Not sure if this will work for your specific scenario, but I've had success triggering mouseover instead of hover for various cases.

Comment: fwiw, I have found that this will not load images if there is a style rule for :hover that specifies a background image.

Comment: mouseover is different from CSS :hover. So this won't work. It can only work in situation where a mouseover event has been bound on something.

Comment: Funny enough i kept trying different ways to add classes but this did solve my issue... its useful answer under circumstances.

Comment: I think this method is better then the one above as it does not require another class to be added to change the elements style.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution I have come across is on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers).
This short jQuery code allows all your hover effects to show on click or touch..
No need to add anything within the function.

```
$('body').on('touchstart', function() {});
```

Hope this helps.