# Adding a :hover effect in Mobile Safari when the user "taps"

Tags: iphone, css, ios, hover, mobile-safari

Is it possible to trigger a `:hover` event whenever a Mobile Safari user single taps on a div area?

It does not have to be a link. Actually, it can't be a link because the user will go to another webpage.

The hover effect I have applied is actually on a div : `#div:hover {color:#ccc;}`
I would like for this hover to happen whenever an iPad or iPhone user single taps on the div area.

<strike>I know that piece of CSS exists for the background color of a link:
`-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(200,0,0,0.4);`
But this does not apply to my situation.</strike>

If this could apply to the color of the text, for example, then I could use it.

Update: **Please see my accepted answer below**

Comment: This seems to be an answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to trigger :hover when a user taps on a div area without using javascript. This is done using `display:none;` and `display:block;`.

For example:

```
<div class="block">
    <p>This content is shown *before* the user hovers over .block or taps .block on an iOS device.</p>
    <div class="mask">
        <p>This content is shown *after* the user hovers over .block or taps .block on an iOS device.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:black;
}

.mask {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:gray;
    display:none;
}

.block:hover .mask {
    display:block;
}
```

I have found that the :hover only triggers on iOS while using `display` (as opposed to `opacity`). Also, CSS transitions ignores `display` so this cannot be transitioned with CSS. If you'd like the transition for desktop users, you can add `opacity:0;` and `opacity:1;`

EDIT: CSS `visibility` also seems to work.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about this in context with `UIWebview`? You can inject CSS or Javascript and treat it as any other browser. If you are doing so I would suggest [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

If you are not using `UIWebView` then we need to define gesture recognizers on the `UIView` and handle the gestures. i.e. in the gesture handlers make a hover uiview and remove it as the user tap is gone...

Comment: i think he's talking about mobile safari

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I am talking about just using CSS in mobile safari. I realize that was unclear.

Comment: Yea, I was wondering if this was only possible using javascript. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about javascript to do this kind of thing. (Especially using javascript along with tapping on an iOS device)