# CSS change div bg when finger is on it (ipad)

Tags: css, ipad, focus

```
#numpad table td#key1 {
  background-image: url("1.png");
}
#numpad table td#key1:active,
#numpad table td#key1:focus {
  background-image: url("1d.png");
}
```

this works like i want it to on the computer (the image changes when i push my mouse key down on it), but it has no effect on the ipad. how can i do this on ipad so that when my finger is on one of the images it will change it with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do that using pure CSS on a touch device.

Here are some [Javascript based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers) answers.