# How to simulate hover effect on touch devices?

Tags: jquery, mobile, hover

I have a web page with some css3 animation on hover and I would like to make it work on iPad (and any touch enabled device) when the user touch these elements.
Here's my code:

html:

```
<div id="headBlock">
    <a id="arm"></a>
    <div id="head">
        <div id="blink"></div>
        <div id="lid"></div>
        <div id="man"></div>
        <a id="man-arm"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
//arm
$('#arm').hover(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('style').css('bottom','244px');
    $(this).addClass('hover_effect');

    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover_effect');
});

//man arm
$('#man').hover(function(){
    $('#man-arm').removeAttr('style');
    $('#man-arm').addClass('hover_effect');

    }, function(){
        $('#man-arm').removeClass('hover_effect');
});
```

You can see that when the mouse enter the elements I remove the style then apply a style and add the css class 'hover_effect' and when the mouse leaves I remove the 'hover_effect' class.
How can I achieve the same thing on touch devices? The click event doesn't have the a callback so I cannot remove the 'hover_effect' class after the click happens. I tried mousedown and mouseup but it didn't work. I searched stackoverflow and I found this [How do I simulate a hover with a touch in touch enabled browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers) but it didn't have any effect.
Any idea anyone?

Thanks
Mauro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$('#arm').bind('touchstart', function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style').css('bottom','244px');
        $(this).addClass('hover_effect');
});

$('#arm').bind('touchend', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover_effect');
});
```

similarly for `$('#man').`

Answer (score -4):

or you can add `:hover` class under css like `a#man:hover{....}` [same goes if you want the same effect or use diff. colors or image for the diff. results].