# How can I add click events with JavaScript (or CSS) on iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I’m having trouble with a hover technique I’m trying to implement on a site. Basically, I have `div` (`.portfolio-item`) which is used to display a `background-image`. The `.portfolio-item` contains one direct child — `<div class="portfolio-item-info">` which is absolutely positioned and is only shown when the user hovers over the parent element.

This works fine on laptops and Android devices but for iOS devices it doesn’t work at all. So if the user touches the `.portfolio-item` div, nothing happens.

#### HTML

```
<div class="portfolio-item" style="background-image: url('path/to/url')">
    <div class="portfolio-item-info">
        <h3 class="font-secondary-bold">Some Title</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
            <li>Publication</li>
            <li>Print</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#">Take a look</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.portfolio-item {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    min-height: $portfolioItemHeight;

    &:before {
        content: "";
        background-color: $colorLight;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        min-height: $portfolioItemHeight;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

    &:hover,
    &:focus {

        &:before {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .portfolio-item-info {
            top: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

To make it work I’m using something really hacky, I’m putting an `onclick` attribute on the `.portfolio-item` div e.g.

```
<div class="portfolio-item" onclick="void(0)" style="background-image: url('path/to/url')">
```

This hacky solution **does** work but I’d ideally like something less… *hacky*.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to replicate hover on touch devices - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970280/how-to-simulate-hover-effect-on-touch-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standard defines how touch devices should deal with hover and it's up to the browser vendor, so any solution will be a kind of 'hack'. However, the following one is more reliable:

Using jQuery you can turn the class `hover` on / off on touch start / end

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.portfolio-item').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    });
});
```

In CSS you add the `.hover` class with the same parameters as existing `:hover`.

Comment: Hi Alexander, unfortunately I’ve found that this only works in iOS 8 :-( In iOS 7.1 the hover class is only added when you touch it — meaning that you have to press down and hold on `.portfolio-item` for `.portfolio-item-info` to appear. On iOS 8, I tap once and `.portfolio-item-info` appears, then stays until I tap again. What is the difference between the JS for iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.

Comment: P.S. just to avoid confusion, I always test on Mobile Safari in iOS.

Comment: Yes, iOS 7 requires 'touch ans hold'. In iOS 8 it was improved :)

Comment: It seems that the `onclick="void(0)"` approach is what is recommended on Apple’s Safari Web Content Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6