# How do I create a DIV that drops down another DIV on :hover (for desktop) and on tap (for touch devices) using CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover, touch, tap

**The Situation**

I want to create a `<div>` which triggers another `<div>` to execute `visibility:visible` from being hidden on `:hover`. I have done this using this CSS code:

```css
#MAIN_NAVIGATION { /* Styling goes here */ }

#NAVIGATION_POP_DROP {
visibility: hidden;}

#MAIN_NAVIGATION:hover > #NAVIGATION_POP_DROP {
visibility: visible;}

#MAIN_NAVIGATION:hover { /* Changes original styling to change BG color */}
```

`#MAIN_NAVIGATION` is the div id that is used for the div that accepts the hover.
`#NAVIGATION_POP_DROP` is the div that is shown when mouse is hovered on `#MAIN_NAVIGATION`

**The Problem**

The CSS above works using desktops/laptops. I have searched for a solution for the "hover" to work on touch devices as well. The problem is that when I tap on the `#MAIN_NAVIGATION`, the `#NAVIGATION_POP_DROP` doesn't close even if I tap on another element. The only action that triggers the `#NAVIGATION_POP_DROP` to disappear is when I tap on another div bearing the `#MAIN_NAVIGATION` id.

**The Question**

On touch devices, how do I hide the `#NAVIGATION_POP_DROP` div again by:
(1) tapping on another element,
(2) scrolling the screen, or
(3) tapping on the same `#MAIN_NAVIGATION` div?

Note: The `#MAIN_NAVIGATION` div element doesn't bear a link.

The effect I want is similar to the menu of [Mashable](http://mashable.com).

I hope somebody could help me. I'm new in using CSS and I don't have much knowledge in designing for touch devices. Thank you.

Comment: normally the `:hover` becomes a `:active` on mobile devices and tablets

Comment: Hover events on touch devices aren't great for interface elements because they're unreliable and tricky to predict (because there's no real world hover action for touch). Would you be happy with a jQuery solution?

Comment: Just something I picked up, you say "...another div bearing the `#MAIN_NAVIGATION` id. I doubt it's got anything to do with your problem, but an ID should be unique. If you need to give two elements the same styles, use a class instead.

Comment: There are some nice JS solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers?rq=1

Comment: @ErikMes I tried replacing `:hover` with `:active` but it doesn't work on my iPad still.

Comment: @GusRuss89 Hello! I'm sorry I had a mistake in my question. What I meant was the `#MAIN_NAVIGATION` div only disappears when I click another clickable div (e.g. `#MAIN_NAVIGATION_2`).

Comment: Hello @TomMaitland is jQuery the only solution? I'm not really familiar with jQuery but I'm willing to take a shot.

Comment: jQuery would be a fairly solid solution, not the only one. The answer in @ralph.m comment is all it would need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the pseudo-selector :after, like so:

```
#MAIN_NAVIGATION:hover:after {
visibility: visible; content:'the content of your new div'; /* add any style here*/}
```

See my example working:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/wNrdp/
```