# Pure <div> pure css dropdown menus, making them clickable on touch browsers, iOS, iPad?

Tags: jquery, touch, mobile-safari, amazon-silk

I have some menus in legacy code structured like so:

```
<div id="show-hide-facets-button">iOS/Touch Browser Popdown Test
    <div id="show-hide-facets-dropdown">
        <ul>
        <li class="show-hide-facets-row" id="item1">Item One</li>
        <li class="show-hide-facets-row" id="item2">Item Two</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The popdown is hidden until hover:

```
#show-hide-facets-button {
}
#show-hide-facets-dropdown {
    display: none;
}
#show-hide-facets-button:hover #show-hide-facets-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

A jsfiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/brycenesbitt/y3kb7/

Note there are no anchors or other clickable elements.  In this case what's a clean way to introduce a clickable element at the top level, so mouse browser users can continue to hover, but touch browser users can access the menu items using a click?  The menu items are all activated with jquery and the touch browsers work fine there.

Comment: Similar but less clear questions include: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984720/how-do-i-create-a-div-that-drops-down-another-div-on-hover-for-desktop-and-on

Comment: Note the jsfiddle site, as of this writing, does not work well on the iPad, and the example above is untestable at jsfiddle.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cleanest solution on the Apple developer site:

```
<div id="show-hide-facets-button" onclick = "void(0)">
```

Adding a do-nothing onclick handler.  Mobile safari will issue a mousemove and click onto this element when touched. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 5):

Yup, it can be a little bit tricky to get the hover pseudo-class to work as desired for drop-down menus on a touch device. If a jQuery plugin is an option, you might consider Superfish. The Silk Developer Guide has a page that discusses [the Superfish solution for hover menus](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/hover-menu.html).

Good luck!