# Javascript show menu on hover for iPad only

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, onclick, responsive-design

The menu on [this site](http://www.rubytuesdayknits.co.uk/?product=little-fox-scarf) doesn't show when using an iPad. It's designed so that the menu is hovered on and the `ul li` list below should show, but it doesn't. When you click the menu, nothing appears.

I need to write some JS using `onclick` events instead to make the sub menu show. But this needs to be specific for iPad ONLY.

Is it possible to write JS specific to only certain devices?

I just need to get this menu working, it seems iPads will not show hover items even when you click... which renders the entire use of `:hover` defunct on iPads.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use browser sniffing to detect the mobile touch devices. Don't do it yourself, use one of the excellent scripts from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

You will needs to do this for iphones, androids, phones etc. anything with a touch screen.

Comment: OK thanks, such a pain that hover seems to work on so many sites except mine... great. Responsive menus are a joke.

Comment: Take a look at some of the mobile frameworks if you are targeting mobile. jquery mobile for example

Comment: This is a really hard issue actually. See http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259848/how-to-deal-with-hover-effect-on-touch-devices