# Hover effect on mobile touch devices (iPhone, Android, Windows)

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover

I'm trying to figure out a way to simulate a hover effect for mobile devices. I've searched around but none seem to work.

The element i'm trying to get to have a mobile hover effect is a link that changes color on hover.

Comment: 1+ I have been trying to figure out the same thing. I'll put a bounty on it if it doesn't get an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers

Comment: tried that, didn't work

Answer (score 6):

Good point it may well have a lot to do with the actual phone you are testing on. I usually test with android which seems to cater for long-press and slide-off (so there is no `onMouseUp` event) by triggering the `:hover` or `:focus` state.

It really begs the question though, if a user is really unlikely to trigger this state, is it worth designing for? `:Hover` is designed for desktop use with a mouse, replicating these interactions on mobile seems counter-productive.

That said, if you are trying to achieve some really interesting interaction for mobile, because it is hard to trigger a hover state without triggering the `onMouseUp` event, you may be better using elements that do not have links attached to allow clicks without triggering a link.

jQuery has `event.preventDefault()` which may help for other needs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Adam! I might just use a media query for now.

Answer (score 4):

New smart phones on the market actually support hover without having to call any JS to make it work.  Regular links with the a:hover anchor pseudo classes will achieve the hover action as long as the smart phone supports the hover 'gesture'.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/technologies/floating-touch/

Answer (score 1):

to give mouseover effect in javascript we have to use `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js`,  from ui js we get two important function `droppable(); and draggable();`
which allows the element to drag and drop but this override `draggable = true` in HTML5
so if we want to use same code for dekstop as well as phone then use as follows

```
 //media query 
 var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 992px)" );

 if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at less than 992px
    jqueryobject.draggable();
 }
 else {
    // window width is at gratet than 992px
 }
```

so we can run same code in dekstop as well as mobile
now the second important point, In HTML5 we use `dragstart(), dragleave(), dragover(), drop()` for different opration related to drag and drop but in mobile we required `touchstart(), touchmove(), touchend() and touchcancel()` for drag and drop which we get from `jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js`, but for mouse over effect we have to use logic as follows

```
<div id=drag_el > and <div id=drop_el>
```

when we drag element touchmove event is fire so in that use

```
  var elementTouching = document.elementFromPoint(first.clientX,first.clientY);
      if(elementTouching.id == "drop_el") {
          //apply u'r css effect like
           elementTouching.style.zoom = "120%";
        }
      else{
          // apply normalize effect of css like
            elementTouching.style.zoom = "100%";
       }
```

It gives you zooming effect on moseover.