# create a button that will display mouseover text

Tags: html

I know how to create help text with a mouseover event.

However, this doesn't work when using a smart phone.

Is there a way to create a button that, when clicked, will display help text that looks the same as the mouseover help text?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers

Comment: On mobile devices, there's no such thing as **hover.**  I think you mean **active.**

Answer (score 2):

`hover` doesn't exist on mobile devices, and I'm guessing you're meaning while the user touches the Element.  If this is the case, I see you have two options:

---

**1 (CSS)** Use `:active`

Example:

`Element:active{ /* Stuff to do */ }`

---

**2 (Javascript)** Use `ontouchstart`

```
Element.ontouchstart = function(e)
{
    //hovering
};
```

or

```
Element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e)
{
    //Hovering!
});
```

---

I'll leave you to the rest, because as you said: `I know how to create help text with a mouseover event.`

Comment: Make sure you accept this answer if it worked for you, or say that it didn't.