# Transferring Hover effects to Tap for Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design, css-transitions

I know this topic has been covered before on this site, and I tried to implement the jQuery from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers) before coming here, and it worked in some instances but not all. In fact, it worked on mobile, but made it stop working on desktop. So i changes everything back to how it was in order to get some accurate help.

I am trying to convert a major hover effect on the desktop to be a tap effect on touchscreen devices. I am not super skilled with javascript yet, so i am trying to find the easiest way to go about it. My effect is a css animation that acts upon hover. Here is my [site](http://www.hollymakes.com/project-i-love-you) and here is my css code for the animation right now.

Thanks so much for any help.

```
.letter {
transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease-in-out;
transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

}

```
.letter div {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

}

```
.side-b {   
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

}

```
#letter_wrap {
-webkit-perspective:1000px; 
-moz-perspective:1000px;
```

}

```
#letter_wrap:hover div.letter {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-.5turn);
-moz-transform: rotateY(-.5turn);
```

}

/*--Transition Delays--*/

```
#letter_i , #letter_v , #letter_o2{
transition-delay: .1s ;
-moz-transition-delay: .1s ;
-webkit-transition-delay: .1s ;
```

}

```
#letter_space , #letter_e , #letter_o{
transition-delay: .2s ;
-moz-transition-delay: .2s ;
-webkit-transition-delay: .2s ;
```

}

```
#letter_l , #letter_y {
transition-delay: .3s ;
-moz-transition-delay: .3s ;
-webkit-transition-delay: .3s ;
```

}

Comment: Sorry, it's a bad (responsive) design if it depends on :hover. The best solution would be to change the design instead of working around with weird hacks.