# CSS - Simulate :hover effect on touchscreen devices

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I can't make [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers) work properly,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
});
```

can you please have a look at my [JSFiddle test script](http://jsfiddle.net/M925P/1/)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding 'touchstart touchend' to '.hover', however there is no element having class 'hover'. Try bind to 'p' like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
    });
});
```

or a more explicit selector other than just 'p'.

Also, your jsfiddle did not load jQuery lib.

http://jsfiddle.net/8PxXL/