# how to detect touch hover with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with Javascript plugin I'm developing. It is a carousel plugin.  The issue is how to detect when the carousel is touched on for a period of time; like a mouse hover. The issue is accompany with "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" message.
http://jsfiddle.net/ospena/xDf4Z/20/

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@author       Oscar Peña - @os-pena
@link            ???
@github        https://github.com/os-pena/Elegant-jQuery-Carousel-Slider
@version     0.0.2
@license      ISC license
based on Simple-jQuery-Carousel-Slider : https://github.com/paulmason/Simple-jQuery-Carousel-Slider

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


jQuery(function ($) {

    // settings
    var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
    var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a li
    var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
    var $time_between_slides = 2300; // 2.3 seconds
    var $interval;

    function slides() {
        return $slider.find($slide);
    }

    slides().fadeOut();

    // set active classes
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

    // auto scroll 
    function startloop() {
        $interval = setInterval(

        function () {
            var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

            slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
            slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

            if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

            slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
            slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
        }, $transition_time + $time_between_slides);
    }
    function pauseLoop() {
        window.clearInterval($interval);
    }

    $slider.hover(

    function () {
        pauseLoop(); // pause the loop
    },

    function () {
        startloop(); //scroll()
    });

    $slide.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    alert ('paused');
    e.preventDefault()
    }, false);

    $slide.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    alert ('paused');
    startloop(); 
  e.preventDefault()
 }, false)



    return startloop();
});
```

Comment: this can be a solution for you

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2891155/2043592

Comment: @xploshioOn this answer is done with javascript and css.  The plugin functionality i'm building is in javascript only.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [taphold](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) event.

```
$("div").on( "taphold", function (event) { ... } );
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on the code in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) .   I tried this code but it error out with the message "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" .  Then,: I added the jQuery mobile library cnd but nothing.