# Mouseover event on Mobile devices - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, touch

I'm developing an hyrid mobile app using AngularJS and Mobile Angular UI, but I'm kind of new about these frameworks.
I need to detect a touch over event, just like mouseover for a desktop app.

The event is different form a swipe event, since I want the event to be triggered even if I start the swipe action outside the target.

Is there a way to do that (without using jQueryMobile)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers

Comment: Not really. That answer explains how to replicate hover when doing a long touch. What I need is basically intercepting all the <div>'s that I touch while swiping with my finger on a mobile device, just like the ng-mouseover attribute in AngularJS, or the .hover(function(){}); in jQuery for mouse events.