# css hover on mobile with css hexagon works kinda buggy

Tags: css, mobile, hover

In my project, I have a grid of hexagons (made with CSS). On the desktop they flip (and therefore change color) when hovering over them. I want the same effect on my smartphone.

I'm using XAMPP to test on my mobile (iPhone 5).

I have tried the code below (stackoverflow-link) but this makes some strange buggy effects when touching the hexes on mobile. It works better (still not perfect) when I add the page to my homescreen from Safari.

The HTML and CSS can be found here:
[codepen](http://codepen.io/Grsmto/pen/rneyo/)

This is what I am doing at the moment but that does not work properly as mentioned above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
    });
});
```

and this added to my CSS

```
element:hover, element.hover_effect {
    rule:properties;
}
```

which I have from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers)

Comment: Can you please me more specific with what you mean by "buggy"?

Comment: when i touch a hex from the grid, hexas around this begin to flash and blink strange, its hard to describe. after the touch they do change color like i wanted but not with that smooth animation