# List items as dropdown menu: fails on Safari

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, safari

I'm using list items for a dropdown menu, originally with `:hover`.   Works well with mouseovers on desktop, but not touchscreen taps.  First implemented advice to simulate the hover state with JavaScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23012580/320036) (referred by @z0r):

```
$('body').bind('touchstart', function() {});
```

Then, all `:hover` selectors were duplicated as `:active`, eg:

```
ul.Menu li:hover>ul,  
ul.Menu li:active>ul {display:block;}
```

Although the submenu displays on iPhones (Safari) with a menu tap, it can't be selected: the submenu disappears.  Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/7jfo9x8h/2.

I'm not sure if the problem is browser/OS specific, but I think it works on Android/Chrome.  Any solutions need to be tested on iPhone (I do not own one).  Thanks in advance!

*Second Q:* I used `cursor:pointer` within css to show the box around MENU is clickable [thanks @DOC ASAREL, great tip].  But with html below and css shown in fiddle (updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/7jfo9x8h/9), only the text is clickable/hoverable.  What css mods are needed to make the full box active (click & hover)?     Many thanks.

```
<ul class="Menu">
  <li>MENU
   <ul>
    <li><a href="...
```

Comment: You will not have luck with `:active`. On mobiles you will need `click`. (ProTip: Add `cursor:pointer` to the clickable elements)!

Comment: I'm inexperienced in css. What exactly do I put in my code?  And should I remove or retain my :active lines? Tnx

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` lines are not needed anymore with this solution. They anyway solve only half the problem.

```js
$('body').bind('touchstart', function() {});

var down = function() {
    $('ul.Menu li ul').slideDown(100)
    $('ul.Menu li').one('click', up)
}
    
var up = function() {
    $('ul.Menu li ul').slideUp(100)
    $('ul.Menu li').one('click', down)
} 

$('ul.Menu li').one('click', function() {
    down()
})
```

```css
/* The css copied from another site;  efforts to prune items may have left a few that are unnecessary */
ul.Menu ul{ display:none; }
ul.Menu li:hover>ul,
ul.Menu li:active>ul{ display:block; }
ul.Menu ul { 
    position: absolute;
    left:-1px;top:98%; 
}
ul.Menu,ul.Menu ul {
 list-style:none;
 padding:0px 2px 2px 0px;
 background-color:#E3D8E3;
 border-width:1px;
 border-style:solid;
}
ul.Menu { float: left; }
ul.Menu li{ margin:0px 10px 0px 5px; }
ul.Menu a, ul.Menu li.dis a:hover,
           ul.Menu li.dis a:active,
ul.Menu li.sep a:hover,
ul.Menu li.sep a:active {
 display:block;
 border-width:0px;
 padding:4px;
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-right:0px;
 font:bold 15px Trebuchet MS;
 color: #050505;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.Menu ul li { float:none; }
ul.Menu ul a { white-space:nowrap; }
ul.Menu li:hover,
ul.Menu li:active{ position:relative; }
ul.Menu li a:hover,
ul.Menu li a:active{
 position:relative;
 background-color:#0000FF;
 border-color:#665500;
 border-style:solid;
 font:bold 15px Trebuchet MS;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--- bootstrap (used for the full version of the site) -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p>
<ul class="Menu">
  <li><font style="font-size:20px;">MENU</font>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="http://cnn.com">Sub 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://cnn.com">Sub 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://cnn.com">Sub 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://cnn.com">Sub 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://cnn.com">Sub 5</font></a></li>
     <li><a href="http://cnn.com">Return Home</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You need a `one` trigger, because you need to change the event that happens on `click` on the same element. Is that what you need? %)P

**Second question**

You had to add the `click` event to `ul.Menu`. And add `position:relative` to `ul.Menu`.

Like in the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7jfo9x8h/10/.

Comment: I'd like to retain hover for mouseovers.  Does your solution disable that? (It seems to.)  Also, after clicking Menu, if I move off submenu w/o making a selection, the submenu appears at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I commented the passage out of the `CSS`, but enabled it again. This is all to accompany you on the way, not to pass you the whole situation. Teaching to fish, not giving fish. ;)

Comment: Thanks.  My friend may have time today to test my site, will update you.  To clarify: I need no `:active` selectors for these effects? I've added a css question in the main section above about making the box _surrounding_ MENU active.

Comment: Hi, no, you do not need the `:active` effect. Active it is only while being clicked / on `mousedown`. Have fun with it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  I now am fishing :)    Did you see my second question above, in main section, about how to make the box surrounding the MENU text hover- and click-able?

Comment: You are welcome. I already updated the answer with a reply to your second question. For `:hover` you had to do `ul.Menu:hover>li ul{display:block}`. Have fun.