# Simulating hover with a touch on touch-enabled browsers - hover elements not going away

Tags: jquery, css, hover, touch

I'm using CSS text tooltips on my site, and I want them to work on touch devices as well. I tried Rich Bradshaw's solution from here
[How do I simulate a hover with a touch in touch enabled browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers) and it works, up until the point where the user stops touching. Then the tooltip box doesn't go away. Not until another tooltip box is activated, or the page is reloaded. Clicking outside it, clicking the link again, etc, doesn't help.

Any tips to 'sharpen' the code a bit so the tooltip box goes away in an orderly fashion? For example adding another option: 'when tooltip is showing and link is clicked, make tooltip go away'? (you can tell I'm not a coder :)