# onmouseover doesn't work for android mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I am using the onmouseover to start a function for mobile devices for a website. The function is to make a dropdown menu dropdown. The function is called and works on iphones, but not on androids. Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `onmouseover` on devices that simply do not support a mouse?  Seems like time to consider if you're trying to put a square peg in a round hole

Comment: [Of (potential) interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113082/detecting-hover-or-mouseover-on-smartphone-browser)

Answer (score 0):

There is no mouse to move in a touch environment like android. The common approach is to detect a long-press for some special actions.

There is also a `onpointermove` event associated to a more generic pointer as in mobile devices, but there is no full support for it. However, some devices could not report any mouse/pointer movement event, because there is no movable pointer.

See also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onpointermove (event)

https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#widl-GlobalEventHandlers-onpointermove (W3C Specification)

Answer (score 0):

You can register a touch event on the same element:

- ontouchcancel: The event occurs when the touch is interrupted
- ontouchend: The event occurs when a finger is removed from a touch screen
- ontouchmove: The event occurs when a finger is dragged across the screen
- ontouchstart: The event occurs when a finger is placed on a touch screen

In this case "ontouchstart" will be the adecuated, or maybe the "onclick" event will be good too.