# onmouseover -mouseout images

Tags: javascript, html

How could  I have two pictures,one for show while I am onmouseover and one for hide while I am onmouseout?

```
<td id="img" onmouseover="showIt(this.src)" onmouseout="hideIt()" src="image1.jpg " src="default.jpg">my box" </td>
    
    
    function showIt(imgsrc)
    {
    document.getElementById('img').src=imgsrc;
    }
    
    function hideIt()
    {
    document.getElementById('img').src="default.png";
    }
```

Comment: `td id="img"`? Should it not be `<img ...`?

Comment: While I have my mouse on this td I want to show one image inside this td, When I do mouseout another image will be shown

Comment: The only argument passed to an EventListener is the EventObject. I would separate your HTML and JavaScript completely. It will save you a world of headaches down the road.

Comment: @klopepen So, to simplify, you will always have an image in `td`. Based on mouse position, it'll change. So it does not have anything to do with `td`. Add an image tag and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using just CSS as well. Note, CSS is always faster than JS in terms of DOM manipulation.

Also as commented, you will have to use `img` tag instead

*CSS Approach*

```css
.hover-toggle {
  content: url('https://reputationtoday.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/110-1102775_download-empty-profile-hd-png-download.jpg');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.hover-toggle:hover {
  content: url('https://img.favpng.com/0/8/3/user-profile-computer-icons-internet-bot-png-favpng-92SBLLR7CwZpN8Vm6MUsuU4Sd.jpg')
}
```

```html
<img class='hover-toggle'>
```

---

As rightly commented by [@StackSlave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2438423/stackslave), hover will have issues on mobile device.

> `:hover` is a problem on mobile. I would use `Element.onmouseenter` and `Element.ontouchstart` and `Element.onmouseleave` and `Element.ontouchend` instead.

JS Approach

```js
function registerEvents() {
  const img = document.getElementById('img');
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', showIt)
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideIt)
}

function showIt() {
  this.src = 'https://img.favpng.com/0/8/3/user-profile-computer-icons-internet-bot-png-favpng-92SBLLR7CwZpN8Vm6MUsuU4Sd.jpg';
}

function hideIt() {
  this.src = 'https://reputationtoday.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/110-1102775_download-empty-profile-hd-png-download.jpg';
}

function initialize() {
  const img = document.getElementById('img');
  // set default state
  hideIt.call(img)
  
  // Register events
  registerEvents()
}

initialize()
```

```css
#img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<img id='img'>
```

#### Reference:

- [Detecting hover or mouseover on smartphone browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113082/detecting-hover-or-mouseover-on-smartphone-browser)
- [Why are inline event handler attributes a bad idea in modern semantic HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737873/why-are-inline-event-handler-attributes-a-bad-idea-in-modern-semantic-html)

Comment: `:hover` is a problem on mobile. I would use `Element.onmouseenter` and `Element.ontouchstart` and `Element.onmouseleave` and `Element.ontouchend` instead.

Comment: @StackSlave Thanks!. I have not worked on a mobile site so would not know.

Comment: It just seems to stay at the `:hover` state.

Comment: @StackSlave Updated answer with references and example for JS approach

Answer (score 0):

use `<img>` tag instead of `<td>`

```
 <img src="ss" onmouseover="add(event)" onmouseout="remove(event)">
```

Java Script

```
function add(e){
          e.target.setAttribute("src", "https://shiharadil.netlify.app/static/media/me.9688d9df.jpg");
}
      
      function remove(e){
          e.target.setAttribute("src", "ss");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to track the original src like this.

```html
<img id="myimg" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/867/volcanic-mt-ngauruhoe-1378772.jpg" onmouseover="mouseover()" onmouseout="mouseout()" />
```

```js
function mouseover() {
  const elm = event.target;
  elm.setAttribute("orig_src", elm.src);
  elm.src = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/647/snowy-mountain-1378865.jpg";
}

function mouseout() {
  const elm = event.target;
  elm.src = elm.getAttribute("orig_src");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/71zfw8s4/

Answer (score 0):

I would separate your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, so everything but the HTML is cached. It also makes it easier to reuse code. Here's an in-depth example, of how I might do what you're asking:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, beacon, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, inArray, shuffle, isNum, isInt, rand; // for reuse on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, func, responseType = 'json', context = null)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(func)func.call(c, x.response);
  }
  x.onerror = e=>{
    if(func)func.call(c, {xhrErrorEvent:e});
  }
  x.send();
  return x;
}
post = (url, send, func, responseType ='json', context = null)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    const c = context || x;
    x.open('POST', url); x.responseType = responseType;
    x.onload = ()=>{
      if(func)func.call(c, x.response);
    }
    x.onerror = e=>{
      if(func)func.call(c, {xhrErrorEvent:e});
    }
    let d;
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      d = send;
    }
    else{
      let s;
      d = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        d.append(k, s);
      }
    }
    x.send(d);
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
beacon = (url, send)=>{
  let r = false;
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    let d;
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      d = send;
    }
    else{
      let s;
      d = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        d.append(k, s);
      }
    }
    r = nav.sendBeacon(url, d);
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return r;
}
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
inArray = (mixed, array)=>{
  if(array.indexOf(mixed) === -1){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
isNum = mixed=>typeof mixed === 'number' && !isNaN(mixed); isInt = mixed=>Number.isInteger(mixed);
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
// magic under here - can put on load on another page except end load
const test = I('test'), one = I('one'), two = I('two');
const presto = ()=>{
  tC(one, 'out'); tC(two, 'out');
}
if(mobile){
  test.ontouchstart = test.ontouchend = presto;
}
else{
  test.onmouseenter = test.onmouseleave = presto;
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; font-size:0; color:#000; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  background:#333; overflow-y:auto;
}
#test{
  position:relative;
}
#test,#test>img{
  width:64px; height:64px;
}
#test>img{
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0; transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out; cursor:pointer;
}
#test>img.out{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='test'>
      <img id='one' src='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-dQCbHQsqFnA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuuclQUPeKb5dc9mdspXEBq7nIrM67RA/s96-c/photo.jpg?sz=64' />
      <img class='out' id='two' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvKY9.png?s=64&g=1' />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Look at `// magic under here` and you'll see the code you can use will be minimal with the above Library I created. Use freely.