# CSS display property not working in mobile browsers

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, display

The document at: http://phoenixchange.com/test/170518_TextTest.html is validated and displays as intended in "most" browsers but still not in e.g mobile Safari.  (pls. see Edit 8 below)  Can anyone explain this and how to fix?

CSS

```
.hideaway {
    font-family: arial;
    font-style: italic;
    }
.hiddentxt {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }
.hideaway .hiddentxt {
    display: none;
    }
.hideaway:hover .hiddentxt {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    font-family: times;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: blue;
    }
```

HTML
`<p>Accusantium doloremque..odit aut fugit.<span class="hideaway"><br><span class="link normal">[more]</span> <span class="hiddentxt"><br> Interested ?  Contact me for details ! </span></span></p>`

....

**EDIT 8**
Code W3C Validated (unnecessary `;` characters e.g `<span class="link normal";>` deleted).  Answer below is re typo in this post only.  The document displays correctly in:
Mobiles: Samsung, Chrome, Firefox
Desktop: Safari, Firefox, IE, Opera
but still **not** in:
Mobiles: Opera Mini, Safari
Safari mobile obviously, and Opera Mini too, are important mobile browsers so I really want any code to work on these (i.e with "current millenium" browsers).  I've had no success finding specific information re CSS that does not function on them / on a safe html/css subset for "current millenium" (mobile) browsers.

Comment: Have you tried using display:flex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers

Comment: I hadn't.  If I understand, `flex` specifies a length for the hidden element? The issue here though is that there is no `:hover` change to the element at all.  The browsers don't recognise any of it for some reason.
EDIT - my mistake! `display:flex` _"Displays an element as a block-level flex container. New in CSS3"_.  Still, the problem I have here is no recognition rather than incorrect action.

Comment: BUT THANK YOU!! That feature is useful to know about!  The page I posted tested typography and layout.  The inline hidden-text is not designed for the situation it's used in there but it provides a way to see how it works (or doesn't in this case!).

Answer (score 0):

`<span class="hideaway"` is missing a `>`

That is why you should always use white space and coding programs (and not notepad)!

```css
.hideaway {
    font-family: arial;
    font-style: italic;
    }
.hiddentxt {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }
.hideaway .hiddentxt {
    display: none;
    }
.hideaway:hover .hiddentxt {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    font-family: times;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<p>
    Accusantium doloremque..odit aut fugit.
    <span class="hideaway">
        <br>
        <span class="link normal";>
            [more]
        </span> 
        <span class="hiddentxt">
            <br> 
            Interested ?  Contact me for details ! 
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

Edit and check code at https://drivenotepad.github.io/

[You could use the title attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp)

> The title attribute specifies extra information about an element.
>
> The information is most often shown as a tooltip text when the mouse moves over the element.

```html
<p title="Interested ?  Contact me for details !">[more]</p>
```

This will show more information once they hover over the element with title.

Comment: FF might autocorrect errors and assume you meant to end the tag, but I would recommend fixing this.  AND use white space!

Comment: Thanks.  That mistake is a typo in the code I copy pasted here. On the page the tag is present. I've edited the OP but left the formatting of the code as is as I am using `white-space: pre-wrap;`.

Comment: Thanks for the ref to the title attribute.