# Having issues with CSS hover on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, hover

I'm building this website using Wordpress. The issue that I am having is that the functionality I set up for the triangular wedge boxes to disappear when hovered over works fine on a desktop, but does not work well on mobile. I've found through research that :hover doesn't work well with mobile, and have tried different pseudo classes like :active and :focus, but with no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Link to My Site](http://ranir.staging.wpengine.com/our-products)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I simulate a hover with a touch in touch enabled browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

A `:hover` event does not exist on touch devices, but you can add `:active`, which should have a similar effect (when the finger touches the element without tapping it), like

```
.my_div:hover, .my_div:active{
   background-color: #fa0;
 }
```