# jQuery hover method on mobile doesn't work on repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I have a hover method that seems to work only on the first pass when its on a mobile device; On desktop it's fine.

Here is a demo:

[image]

Here is the jQuery code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        var $subnav = $('.subnav');
        $(".close").on('click tap', function(e) {
            if ($subnav) $subnav.hide();
            else $subnav.show();
        });

        $(".discover, .watch").hover(
            function(e) {
                $(this).find($subnav).show();
            },
            function() {
                $(this).find($subnav).hide();
            }
        );
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $subnav = $('.subnav');
  $(".close").on('click tap', function(e) {
    if ($subnav) $subnav.hide();
    else $subnav.show();
  });

  $(".discover, .watch").hover(
    function(e) {
      $(this).find($subnav).show();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find($subnav).hide();
    }
  );
});
```

```css
/* Header / Nav Section */

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
}

header .header {
  height: 58px;
  position: relative;
}

header .globalLogo img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 350;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 300;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

nav ul li {
  font-family: Brown Bold, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  word-spacing: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}

header nav ul:not(:hover).discover-active .discover .nav-category {
  color: #ef4b4b;
}

nav ul li .nav-category {
  padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
  height: 58px;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul:not(:hover).discover-active .discover .nav-category:before {
  background-color: #ef4b4b;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.discover:hover .nav-category:before {
  background-color: #ef4b4b;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.watch:hover .nav-category:before {
  background-color: #e5059a;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

.discover .subnav,
.watch .subnav,
.global-site-switch .subnav {
  display: none;
}

.discover .subnav img {
  width: 100%;
}

header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.discover .subnav {
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 59px;
  height: 530px;
  width: 635px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.watch .subnav {
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 59px;
  height: 530px;
  width: 635px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

header .global-site-switch:hover .subnav {
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  left: -30px;
  top: 47px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

nav ul li .nav-category .nav-category-padding {
  position: relative;
  top: 17px;
}

nav ul li .nav-category .fa-angle-down {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  width: auto;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .4;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 18px;
}

header div.header .global-site-switch {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 12px;
  right: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 350;
}

header .global-site-switch .subnav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

header .global-site-switch .subnav a img {
  width: 25px;
  margin: -3px 10px 0 0;
}

header .global-site-switch .subnav a span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Brown Bold, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

header div.header .global-site-switch .country {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header div.header .global-site-switch .country img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* height: 14px; */
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 8px 5px;
}

header div.header .global-site-switch .fa {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  height: 12px;
  width: 11px;
}

header div.header .global-site-switch .label {
  font-family: Brown Regular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  display: inline-block;
}

header div.header .global-site-switch ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

header .global-search-nav.active .search-drawer,
header .global-search-nav.active .search-drawer #search-header,
header .global-search-nav.active .search-drawer .search-close {
  display: inline-block;
}

header .global-search-nav {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  top: -58px;
  right: 0;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1100px;
  z-index: 350;
}

header .global-search-nav.active {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 375;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

header .global-search-nav .search-button {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 375;
}

header .global-search-nav.active .search-button {
  display: none;
}

header .global-search-nav .search-button .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .global-search-nav .search-drawer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 375;
}

header .global-search-nav .search-drawer form {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header .global-search-nav .search-drawer #search-header {
  font-family: Playfair Display, serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: normal;
  letter-spacing: -.02em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}

header .global-search-nav .search-drawer .search-close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url(/images/close.svg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  color: #000;
}




/* Header */

@media only screen and (max-width: 760.98px) {
  header.navbar {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  header.navbar div.header {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 38px;
  }
  header.navbar div.header .global-site-switch {
    color: #000;
    top: 3px;
  }
  header.navbar div.header .global-site-switch:hover .subnav {
    top: 30px;
    height: 142px;
    padding: 14px 0;
  }
  header.navbar div.header .global-search-nav {
    top: -38px;
  }
  header .global-search-nav .search-button .fa-search {
    top: 28px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    color: #000;
  }
  header.navbar div.header nav {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    border-top: 4px solid #fff;
    height: 45px;
    top: 38px;
  }
  header.navbar div.header .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.discover:hover .nav-category:before,
  header.navbar div.header .nav-categories:not(:hover).discover-active .discover .nav-category:before,
  header.navbar div.header .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.watch:hover .nav-category:before {
    top: -4px;
  }
  header.navbar div.header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav:hover .subnav {
    top: 83px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header.navbar div.header .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav {
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    word-spacing: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  header.navbar div.header .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav .nav-category .nav-category-padding {
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 11px;
  }
  header.navbar div.header .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav .nav-category i.fa {
    height: 14px;
  }
  header.navbar div.header .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav .nav-category .fa-angle-down {
    top: 13px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  header .global-search-nav.active .search-drawer,
  header .global-search-nav.active {
    height: 42px;
  }
  header .global-search-nav .search-drawer .search-close {
    right: 20px;
    top: 12px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
  }
  p.close {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1221px) {
  header .header {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  header nav .nav-categories {
    max-width: 535px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1220.98px) and (min-width: 761px) {
  header .globalLogo img {
    height: 50px;
  }
  header .header {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
  header nav .nav-categories {
    max-width: 403px;
  }
  nav ul li .nav-category .nav-category-padding {
    top: 15px;
  }
  nav ul li .nav-category .fa-angle-down {
    margin-left: 3px;
    top: 18px;
  }
  header .global-site-switch {
    right: 80px;
  }
  header .global-search-nav .search-button {
    right: 30px;
  }
  header .global-search-nav .search-drawer .search-close {
    right: 30px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1220.98px) {
  nav ul li .nav-category {
    padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}


/* Main */

@media only screen and (max-width:760.98px) {
  .opener .full-width-opener {
    position: relative;
  }
  .opener .full-width-opener:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 120%;
  }
  .opener .full-width-opener>.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .story-share.article-bottom {
    width: 275px;
  }
  .r29-article .header .title {
    font-family: Playfair Display, serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    word-spacing: normal;
    letter-spacing: -.02em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-transform: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:761px) {
  .story-share.article-bottom {
    width: 165px;
  }
  .body .section-container.left-align {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 20px 20px 0;
  }
  .body .section-container.right-align {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 20px;
  }
  .body .section-container.half-width {
    width: 360px;
  }
  .body .section-container.half-width.left-align,
  .body .section-container.half-width.right-align {
    width: 340px;
  }
  .body .section-container.full-width {
    width: 720px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1220.98px) {
  .r29-article {
    padding: 25px 12px 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .product-carousel {
    width: 100%!important;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  .product-carousel button.slick-arrow.slick-prev svg {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:761px) and (max-width:1220.98px) {
  .r29-article .header .title {
    font-family: Playfair Display, serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    word-spacing: normal;
    letter-spacing: -.02em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-transform: none;
  }
  .product-carousel .product-grid-header {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1221px) {
  .body .section-container.section-asset-container {
    margin: 48px auto;
  }
  .product-carousel .slick-list {
    left: 12px;
  }
}


/* Footer */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1220.98px) {
  .global-footer .social-container .social-nav li+li {
    margin-left: 12px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 761px) {
  .global-footer .social-container .social-nav li+li {
    margin-left: 10.6px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 761px) and (max-width:1220.98px) {
  .global-footer .social-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center
  }
  .global-footer .links {
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 40px 0
  }
  .global-footer .links ul li {
    text-align: center
  }
  .global-footer .email-signup {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto
  }
  .global-footer .email-signup .column-header {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto
  }
  .global-footer .email-signup .footer-email-acquisition {
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    text-align: center
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760.98px) {
  .global-footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto
  }
  .global-footer .social-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center
  }
  .global-footer .links {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 40px 0 0
  }
  .global-footer .links ul li {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.4em
  }
  .global-footer .links.company {
    width: 50%;
    float: left
  }
  .global-footer .links.information {
    width: 50%;
    float: right
  }
  .global-footer .email-signup {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    max-width: 300px
  }
  .global-footer .email-signup .column-header {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto
  }
  .global-footer .email-signup .footer-email-acquisition {
    margin: 15px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-categories discover-active">
        <li class="nav-category-and-subnav discover">
          <div class="nav-category">
            <span class="nav-category-padding">Discover</span> <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-down"><svg height="1792"
                   viewbox="0 0 1792 1792"
                   width="1792"
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M1395 736q0 13-10 23l-466 466q-10 10-23 10t-23-10L407 759q-10-10-10-23t10-23l50-50q10-10 23-10t23 10l393 393 393-393q10-10 23-10t23 10l50 50q10 10 10 23z"></path></svg></i>
            <div class="subnav">
              <a href="https://jump.refinery29.com/join/24/signup-ca-refresh"><img src="images/thisweek.jpg"></a>
              <p class="close">X</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-category-and-subnav watch">
          <div class="nav-category">
            <span class="nav-category-padding">Watch</span> <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-down"><svg height="1792"
                   viewbox="0 0 1792 1792"
                   width="1792"
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M1395 736q0 13-10 23l-466 466q-10 10-23 10t-23-10L407 759q-10-10-10-23t10-23l50-50q10-10 23-10t23 10l393 393 393-393q10-10 23-10t23 10l50 50q10 10 10 23z"></path></svg></i>
            <div class="subnav">
              <div class="column">
                Original Series
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                Trending Videos
              </div>
              <p class="close">X</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23012580/5728516

Comment: `if ($subnav)` will always be true.  jQuery objects, and objects in general, are truthy

Comment: try `.on('mouseover', ...)` instead of `.hover`. also check your if statement like @ChandraSekhar suggests.

Comment: @popshuvit removed tap but to no effect, thanks though. @Taplar I tried: `if(!$subnav) $subnav.show(); else $subnav.hide();` that also had no effect...