# How to fire hover for anchor tag through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link. It hover has some background effects.

I want to fire this hover through jquery.

Comment: Please show us your markup, so we can have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can fire the javascript hover (`mouseover` of `mouseenter` or `mousemove` or something, depending on the js lib), but you can't fire the CSS :hover state with Javascript.

You can only use jQuery to fire the event IF jQuery was used to attach the event.

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) wrapped in `document.ready`, so that it automatically fires up when a hover happens over the link

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#YourLinkId").hover(functionToHandleWhenMouseEnters, 
                             functionToHandleWhenMouseLeaves);
});

function functionToHandleWhenMouseEnters() {
     $(this).css({background : red});
}

function functionToHandleWhenMouseLeaves() {
     $(this).css({background: white});
}
```

**Edit:**

I am note very sure if this is what you wanted, but as per David's comment, it might not be it. If you want to programatically fire (trigger) a hover, then you should use jQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$("#YourLinkId").trigger("mouseover");
```

Comment: The question is about firing it, not defining what will happen when it is fired.

Comment: @David: I have added further information on how to auto fire hover by wrapping it in document.ready, Thanks.

Comment: No, that just doesn't assign the event handlers until document.ready arrives. The act of firing it is done by moving the mouse over it, and the question is about firing it programatically (assuming that w3father knows what 'fire' means).

Comment: @David: OK got you. If that is the case, then he needs trigger(). Correct me if I didn't understand it correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I don't believe you can fire the `:hover` state for a CSS element. I would suggest you handle the hover events for the element and add/remove a special class for your element, for example:

CSS:

`#myElement.myClass {  }`

jQuery:

```
$("#myElement").hover(
    function(){
        //mouse in
        $(this).addClass("myClass");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("myClass");
    });
```

Comment: If we assume that the user have hover effects by css :hover then this is the correct answer. More information can be found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290829/how-to-force-a-hover-state-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#hrefID').trigger('mouseover'); //triggers hover
//your 'hover' code runs....
$('#hrefID').trigger('mouseout'); //removes hover
//your 'mouse out' portion of hover code runs here...
```

see this link on [jQuery Trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)