# Can mouse hover on a menu item trigger the native ":hover" state of another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my website I have 3 sections in the content area. Those have CSS3 animations and stuff going on when a user hovers the mouse.

Now, I thought it might be a good idea to have the same effect going on when users hover the menu items (it is a landing page so basically the menu items have anchors on them, etc)

I was able to use `hover()` method but all that enabled me was adding/removing classes.

My question is: Is there any way jQuery is able to cause the native hover on an element (the elements are not related, that is, truly hovered item is a nav item, and the other is a section in the page content).

Comment: I don't think so. you'll have to do the stuff in css `:hover` selector in a js function… Even if you manage to trigger hover on other elements, won't that be momentary..? or will you keep on triggering hover in a loop or interval as long as on item is hovered..? `add/remove` classes instead.

Comment: see this : [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290829/how-to-force-a-hover-state-with-jquery)

Comment: Yep, I just accompanied my existing `:hover` CSS declarations with `.xyz.hovered` (comma separated, obviously) for each element that needed it and it works.

Comment: @ConductedClever Please move your comment into an answer (even though it's just pointing to another questions) so I can mark it accepted!

Comment: and now i wait for your acceptance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is already answered.

try this :

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $("#link").trigger("hover");
});
```

see the full answer here :

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290829/how-to-force-a-hover-state-with-jquery)

Comment: You should mark this as a duplicate instead of copying the answer from the other question.