# Simulate a shine effect on a button that is executed on hover event, but with other event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my first question

I can't find an answer.
I have been looking on various topics, like this ones (for example):

- [How to force a hover state with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290829/how-to-force-a-hover-state-with-jquery)
- [How do I simulate a mouseover in pure JavaScript that activates the CSS ":hover"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover)

I want to simulate a shining effect on a button that triggers on hover (The effect is just CSS and i took it from this site: https://codemyui.com/pure-css-shining-button-hover-animation/), but with other event, like clicking some other button or whatever.
According to my previous topics research, is not possible to trigger a hover event, so the workaround is assign a class to that hover CSS style,
and thats what i tried to do, but i can't make it work.

I think the problem is because the CSS it has pseudo-elements like **:after**, **:before** and **:hover** and sometimes they are combined.

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300);
.btnShine {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.btnShine {
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: .6s;
  transition: .6s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btnShine:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.test1, .btnShine:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-filter: blur(30px);
          filter: blur(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px) skewX(-15deg);
          transform: translateX(-100px) skewX(-15deg);
}
.test2, .btnShine:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 30px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px) skewX(-15deg);
          transform: translateX(-100px) skewX(-15deg);
}
.test4, .btnShine:hover {
  background: #338033;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.test3, .btnShine:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
          transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-transition: .7s;
  transition: .7s;
}
.test5, .btnShine:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
          transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .7s;
  transition: .7s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Simulate a hover on the Stylized button</button>
<!--this shine effect was taken from this url https://codemyui.com/pure-css-shining-button-hover-animation/-->
<button class="btnShine">hover</button>
```

JS / JQuery:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    //$(".btnShine").trigger("mouseenter");
  //$(".btnShine").trigger("hover");
  //$(".btnShine").trigger("mouseover");
  //$(".btnShine").mouseover();
  $('.btnShine').addClass("test3"); 
  $('.btnShine').addClass("test4"); 
  $('.btnShine').addClass("test5"); 
/*
  $('.btnShine').removeClass("test5");
  $('.btnShine').removeClass("test4");
  $('.btnShine').removeClass("test3");
  */
});
```

I made this JSFiddle, so you guys can understand what i'm trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/kaedfegn/2/

PS: I'm Chilean so my native language is Spanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add the `:before` and `:after` to all your test classes.

So, this:

`.test1, .btnShine:before`

should be this:

`.test1:before, .btnShine:before`

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaedfegn/3/)

I would consider adding all your "test" classes into one class and writing the styles around that 1 class. I combined all of them and called it `.shine` in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaedfegn/5/).

so the selector would look something like this:

```
.btnShine.shine, .btnShine:hover {
  background: #338033;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnShine.shine:before, .btnShine:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
          transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-transition: .7s;
  transition: .7s;
}

.btnShine.shine:after, .btnShine:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
          transform: translateX(300px) skewX(-15deg);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .7s;
  transition: .7s;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, css is the better option than js

Comment: Thank you very much. I really aprecciate your help. It worked.

Comment: @G.Ruiz if it worked you should accepted it as an answer so it can help others

Comment: @zgood i didn't know how to do that, so i googled it. It was so obvious, jajajajaj.
Thanks man.